# How do I filter cloud builder builds on multiple tags?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-build

Is it possible to filter builds containing multiple tags using `gcloud`? The following command returns zero hits, despite there being builds:

`gcloud builds list --filter "tags='issueid-123' AND tags='team-frontend'"`

When filtering on a single tag it returns the expected results. The same seems to be an issue in the filter box in the GCP builds web UI.

Comment: Hmmm.... I agree. I can repro this. I recommend you file a bug against Google for this issue here (https://issuetracker.google.com/savedsearches/5226584). If you'd prefer, I (Googler) will file the bug on your behalf?

Comment: @DazWilkin Thanks for confirming! I've filed an issue: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/113304618

Comment: Ack. Chasing internally too. Thanks for the report!

Comment: may be this may works: `gcloud builds list --filter="tags.items=(issueid-123,team-frontend)"` or `gcloud builds list --filter="tags.items=issueid-123 AND tags.items=team-frontend"` : ref: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/filters

Comment: @DazWilkin @runeh Unfortunately the issue has been closed, but it's definitely still valid: `gcloud compute instances list --filter 'tags.items=foo AND tags.items=bar'` works but  `gcloud builds list --filter 'tags=foo AND tags=bar'` doesn't.

Comment: @Asdfg The first of those is combining the tags with boolean OR, which is already fine - the problem is combining them with AND. The second example illustrates the problem (using "tags" rather than "tags.items") - the documentation says it should work, but it doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dug into this a bit to figure out what is happening and it's a very subtle issue that will take some consideration to fix properly. In the short term, the only work-around I can suggest is to query each tag separately and then filter on your own. :-(

So:

```
gcloud builds list --filter='tags="tag1"' > tag1-list.txt
gcloud builds list --filter='tags="tag2"' > tag2-list.txt
comm -12 tag1-list.txt tag2-list.txt
```

Note that there should be no need to sort the files before the comm because list builds returns builds in sorted order (by time) already.